# First selected item in combobox (selectOneMenu)

Tags: jsf, combobox, selectonemenu

I would like to select a value from a list in the combobox (selectonemenu), but I want to keep "-Mind-" as first selectitem, and then the other selectitems, when I open the combobox. I only want to choose an item in the background, when the page loads, the item need to be selected.

Here is my code:

```
<p:selectOneMenu value="#{indexBean.filter.ev}" converter="javax.faces.Integer" style="width: 70px">
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="-Mind-" itemValue="#{null}"/>
    <f:selectItems value="#{indexBean.evLista}" var="ev" itemLabel="#{ev}" itemValue="#{ev}"/>
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

And the bean:

```
public List<Integer> getEvLista() {
    for (int i = 2015; i >= 2014; i--) {
        evek.add(i);
    }
    return evek;
}
```

I want to be selected e.g: 2015. I have no `@PostConstruct` method yet but maybe that is the solution. Can you help me? Thanks!

Comment: I got such an impression that you want an already selected item to be selected even after a synchronous GET request is sent. The only option in this case is to store the selected item (`value="#{indexBean.filter.ev}`) into the user's session. You appear to be trying to deal with a date(time) picker. Why not using a calendar provided by PrimeFaces in that case. Yes, a `<p:selectOneMenu>` gives an impression of PrimeFaces usage.

Answer (score 0):

Add a `valueChangeListener` to the `p:selectOneMenu` and get / set selected value as a separate property.

```
<p:selectOneMenu value="#{indexBean.selectedYear}" converter="javax.faces.Integer" 
    style="width: 70px" valueChangeListener="#{indexBean.yearValueChangeListener}">
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="-Mind-" itemValue="#{null}"/>
    <f:selectItems value="#{indexBean.evLista}" var="ev" 
        itemLabel="#{ev}" itemValue="#{ev}"/>
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

**Bean:**

```
int selectedYear = 0;

public int getSelectedYear(){
    return selectedYear;
}

public void setSelectedYear(int selectedYear){
    this.selectedYear = selectedYear;
}

public void yearValueChangeListener(ValueChangeEvent vce) {
    if (vce.getNewValue() != null) {
        selectedYear = Integer.parseInt(vce.getNewValue().toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: hmm.. I added the valueChangeListener, and the yearValueChangeListener method. (getter setter not important because I use lombok), I know what did you want to make but that's not work. :/ I tried also in "yearValueChangeListener" method a bit different:
'if (vce.getNewValue() != null || vce.getNewValue() != "")'
but it did not work also. More ideas?

Comment: Then what do you want to achieve?

Comment: I wanted to choose an item in the combobox (so not the "-Mind-" will be show when the page loads, i need show the "2015" firstly), but i want to keep the sequence of items. Sequence is: "-Mind", "2015", "2014"

Comment: I want to keep in the list :) But not want to choose it by default when the page loads, i want choose another value when the page loads, but I want to keep the list sequence, too.

Comment: So what is issue in it? Assign selectedYear = 2015 or the value you want to keep selected on load.

Comment: The list now contains 3 items: "-Mind-", "2015", "2014". Now the "-Mind-" is selected, when the page loads. I'd like to select automatically the "2015" item when the page loads, but i dont want to change the sequence (e.g.: "2015", "2014", "-Mind-") I want to keep the sequence. ("-Mind-", "2015", "2014"). The issue is: I cannot select automatically an item from the list, when the page loads.

Comment: set desired value in init of your bean, that will set selected value for select.

Comment: If the value attribute is not working in your case, you can use binding as well for setting selected value. The issue with the selection is observed in nested components.

Comment: "set desired value in init of your bean, that will set selected value for select."
Maybe that is the solution I think how can I do this?

Comment: set selectedYear to 2015 in the init of your bean